# A função MAIL envia dois e-mails para o destinatário

Tags: php

Utilizo a função mail em diversas partes dos meus projetos, porém, em uma aplicação esta função faz o envio de dois emails para o destinatário.

Não tenho ideia porque isso está acontecendo.

**Segue o código completo:**

```
<?php
include ("./incluir/conexao.php");

$vconteudo = trim($_GET['conteudo']);
$vmail = trim($_GET['emailcopia']);

$noticia_copia=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id, slug, titulo FROM noticias WHERE id = $vconteudo GROUP BY id");
while($painel_noticias_copia=mysqli_fetch_array($noticia_copia))
    {
        $vid = $painel_noticias_copia['id'];
        $vslug = $painel_noticias_copia['slug'];
        $vtitulo = $painel_noticias_copia['titulo'];
    }

                $to = $vmail;
                $subject = $vtitulo;
                $message = "

                <h1>Olá, inscrito!</h1>

                <div style='font-size:17px;'>Segue uma cópia do conteúdo que você solicitou.</div><p>

                <div style='font-size:17px;'>Este material foi preparado com muita dedicação.</div><p>

                <div style='font-size:17px;'><b>Pug: conheça tudo sobre a origem milenar da raça</b></div><p>                   

                <div style='font-size:17px;'>Acesse agora mesmo <a href='https://www.portalvidapet.com.br/{$vid}/{$vslug}' target='_blank'>www.portalvidapet.com.br/{$vid}/{$vslug}</a></div><p>


                ";

                $headers = "From: Portal Vida Pet <contato@portalvidapet.com.br>\n";
                $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
                $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";

                mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);


            $cap_email=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT email FROM captura WHERE email = '$vmail' GROUP BY email");
            if (mysqli_num_rows($cap_email) < 1)
            {
                $painel=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO captura(email) VALUES ('$vmail')");
            }

?>
```

Comment: Acho que o problema está no HTML. Como mencionou o Leandro, a página pode estar sendo chamada 2x.

Comment: a resposta te ajudou? Se sim, procure marcá-la para ajudar outros colegas.

Answer (score 0):

Vamos lá algumas alternativas podem ser verificadas para isto não ocorrer mais:

1) Pressiona **F12** no `Chrome`, vai na guia "`Network`", lá mostra todas as páginas que são acessadas. Veja se essa página não está sendo chamada duas vezes. Por exemplo, por ser chamada duas vezes uma por `method post` e outra `document`

2) Se aparecer duas vezes por exemplo, vc pode colocar um if no seu código para somente se for `method post` você enviar seu `mail()`, assim: (obs.: já aconteceu comigo e consegui resolver com o código abaixo)

```
<?php 
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

//Seu código aqui

}
```

3) Se mesmo assim persistir, verifique sua `action` no `form`;

4) Se ainda assim persistir, crie uma variável de controle e salve no banco seu email enviado, assim verifique se já foi enviado e não envie novamente. Enfim, faria essas verificações para travar enviar duas vezes.

p.s.: procure usar `phpMailer` ao invés de `mail()`